# Direction from origin for a certain distance

Tags: java, minecraft

I want to push a mob a certain distance away from the direction I right click on the mob but when I use this code the distance the mob is pushed away changes depending on how close  or further away I am to the mob.

```
    target.motionX = (target.posX - player.posX) * 0.5;
    target.motionZ = (target.posZ - player.posZ) * 0.5;
```

I know that I need to to get the direction the player is facing then move the mob away from that a certain distance. I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: Well, you have the distance between the target and the player in your formula. Perhaps you wanted just the sign of the distance (orientation).

Comment: What formula would you use?

Comment: I see what you mean now. See my edit, perhaps this is closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to find the distances:

```
float xDis = target.posX - player.posX;
float zDis = target.posZ - player.posZ;
```

If `xDis` is non-zero, calculate the angle:

```
float tangent = zDis / xDis;
float angle = Math.arctan(tangent);
```

Then, decide a length for your throw vector:

```
float length = 0.5;
```

And then the projection on the two axes:

```
float xProj = length*Math.cos(angle)*Math.signum(xDis);
float zProj = length*Math.sin(angle)*Math.signum(xDis);
```

And these are your `motionX` and `motionY` parts.

If `xDis` *is* zero, then I think you'll need this special case.

```
float xProj = 0;
float zProj = length*Math.signum(zDis);
```

Comment: So xProj and zProj would be my motion?

Comment: Yes. I haven't tested the code, but I think it's close to what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, I noticed one mistake in my code. I shouldn't have converted to degrees. See my edit again.

Comment: It kinda works, but it either pushed the mob away or pull it towards me depending how far away I'm from the mob (I think) any idea?

Comment: Try the edited last two lines. Do they solve the issue?

Comment: It's only working now in 2 directions... Getting closer to the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47699/discussion-between-theodoros-chatzigiannakis-and-minigeek22)